# Object Oriented JavaScript Lock

Tags: javascript, oop

I have given below simplified JavaScript problem.

```
var PROJ=(function(){
    var tags={}, 
    var lock=true;
    function onLoadComplete(){}
    this.Tag = function(userConfig,callBack){       
            function loadConfig(){
                    lock=false;             
                    /* Do something privately having lock with me */
                    lock=true;
            }                           
            this.load(){
                  if(lock)  loadConfig();
                  else      setTimeout(load,1000); 
              // PROBLEM is this(above) load is calling OUTER load..!
            }
       return this;
    };

    this.load(){
      var cb=onLoadComplete;
      tags[uniqueID]=new Tag(userConfig,cb);
      tags[uniqueID].load();
    }       
}).load();
```

I am trying to implement JavaScript locks here. Three JavaScript Tag objects  are created. [ new Tag() ]These objects share and modify some public data available in PROJ.

I want to give access to public data when lock has been released by executing Tag. This load mentioned in setTimeout() is calling load() of PROJ.

Comment: You should fix your code. There are syntax errors (those `{}` parentheses probably get ignored by the browsers, so you don't see it), and there is no definition of the `load` function.

Comment: @Umesh as both Groo and FelixKing have stated, your code is not syntatically correct so we can only guess as to your problem. Even though this is cut from a much larger context please make it self consistent and syntatically correct or any answer you get will just be a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am presuming that the code actually looks like this:

```
this.Tag = function(userConfig,callBack){       
        function loadConfig(){
                lock=false;             
                /* Do something privately having lock with me */
                lock=true;
        }                           
        this.load = function(){
              if(lock)  loadConfig();
              else      setTimeout(load,1000); 
        }
   return this;
};
```

Since JavaScript is single threaded, it is not possible for the `load` function to be invoked while `loadConfig` is still running. This means that it is not possible for the  `lock` variable to be `false` inside `load`, unless:

1. There is a `return` statement in `loadConfig` which returns execution **before** `lock` is set to `true`.
2. There is an exception thrown in the middle of the function, and the last line is never executed.

For the latter case, you can use the `try/finally` block to make sure that `lock` is reset in case of an exception:

```
        function loadConfig(){
            try {
                lock=false;             
                /* Do something privately having lock with me */
            }
            finally {
                // this will get executed even if an exception is thrown
                lock=true;
            }
        }
```

The bottom line is, `lock` is not needed at all and can be removed completely. There is no way `load` could run concurrently with `loadConfig`.

Comment: Thanks Groo ! It is much better explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you aware that JavaScript runs in a single thread only? Locks (concurrency) don't do much, unless your inner `loadConfig` function actually recurses or call `load` in some way.

Note that I think that you have your syntax wrong.

```
this.load(){
    if(lock)  loadConfig();
    else      setTimeout(load,1000); 
}
```

is actually doing this:

```
this.load(); // invoke load

if(lock)  loadConfig();
else      setTimeout(load,1000);
```

Comment: The code given is very simplified and minimized. Even JS runs in single threads, Multiple Tags (Tag Object) are being created which runs simultaneously.

Comment: @Umesh: Multiple times !== concurrent.

Comment: @FelixKling, Yes. I want to say, Multiple(concurrent) Tag objects are created here. Can you pls help out here?

Comment: @Umesh: But as Lucero says, JavaScript is single threaded, so JavaScript code cannot be run concurrently, only if you use e.g. web workers and even then they cannot work on the same objects.

Comment: @Umesh, unless you somehow do "manually" create new `Tag` instances inside of the `Tag` function the code will not re-enter. Fix your `this.load` function declarations (?) first and then try again, concurrency is not a problem here.

Comment: @Lucero, You are correct. Actually, it is bigg code(75 KB). I hv put simplified here. if u really want to help. May I send you the whole file ? I will need your mail id.

Comment: @Umesh, use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or even better [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), I don't give my mail address out.

Comment: @Lucero, jsfiddle can not be used here to show web requests :( At least can you come in JavaScript Chat room of stackover flow ?

Comment: @Umesh, you can still post your code so that it can be looked at. As I said before, your problem is not concurrency, have you looked into syntax ambiguities (which JS has some, for instance due to the optional semicolon `;`. I don't have the time to chat right now as I have to leave in about 2 minutes.